# SPFX for favicon published to SharePoint 2019 server not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-extensions, 2019, applicationcustomizers

I have created a SPFx framework extension to change the favicon of my SharePoint 2019 on-premise. I followed below link, everything works fine while testing. but when deployed to app catalog it doesn't change the favicon.

[How To Change The Favicon In SharePoint Modern Site Using SPFx Application Customizer](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-change-the-favicon-in-sharepoint-modern-site-using-spfx-application-customizer/)?

Any help is highly appreciated, I am stuck with this for 3 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to upload sppkg file in app catalog or there is any error? Have you added an app to you sharepoint site? Are you getting any errors in console after adding app in your site?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap I am able to upload sppkg file in app catalog - no error. i have added a test spfx web-part and it worked fine. how to check console for errors? i am creating this app in test server and deploying to real server. (i did the webpart spfx also the same way, which worked)

Answer (score 0):

looks like tenant wide publishing is not possible in SharePoint 2019 server. Deploy the solution and add it in each site, it will work.

reference
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3590